# Update to Service Pack 3 failed - PostSetupConfigurationTaskException

Tags: wss-3.0, service-pack, maintenance

We have a wss 3.0 development farm in product version 12.0.0.6421, which means it is updated up to Service Pack 2. When trying to install Service Pack 3 for wss the following error shows up:

```
"An exception of type Microsoft.Sharepoint.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException.
Error updating Microsoft SharePoint products and technologies."
```

When looking through the config log file this is the info I get:

```
2/11/2012 11:10:05  1  INF                                      Leaving function Command.this[string key]
12/11/2012 11:10:05  1  INF                                      Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
12/11/2012 11:10:05  1  INF                                        Resource id to be retrieved is UpgradeTaskFailConfigSyncDisplayLabel for language Spanish (Spain)
12/11/2012 11:10:05  1  INF                                        Resource retrieved id UpgradeTaskFailConfigSyncDisplayLabel is Error al actualizar Productos y Tecnologías de SharePoint.
12/11/2012 11:10:05  1  INF                                      Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
12/11/2012 11:10:05  1  INF                                      Entering function PsconfigLabel.PsconfigLabel
12/11/2012 11:10:05  1  INF                                        Entering function PsconfigLabel.CommonStuff
12/11/2012 11:10:05  1  INF                                          Created a label, name is FinishForm, text is Error al actualizar Productos y Tecnologías de SharePoint.
12/11/2012 11:10:05  1  INF                                        Leaving function PsconfigLabel.CommonStuff
12/11/2012 11:10:05  1  INF                                      Leaving function PsconfigLabel.PsconfigLabel
12/11/2012 11:10:05  1  INF                                      Entering function PsconfigLabel.PsconfigLabel
12/11/2012 11:10:05  1  INF                                        Entering function PsconfigLabel.CommonStuff
12/11/2012 11:10:05  1  INF                                          Created a label, name is FinishForm, text is Se inició una excepción de tipo Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException. Información adicional de la excepción: Error al actualizar Productos y Tecnologías de SharePoint.
```

It's worth noting  that we are using the spanish language version of wss 3.0.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect that our product version is not MOSS 2007, but WSS 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

This 'bug' is fixed by:

Copy the web.config file in the "12\Config" folder and paste it in "12\Templates\Layouts".
And you can run the SharePoint Products and Technologies Configuration Wizard again.

I've found that this bug as happened to me and this is the blog that fixed it for me. Source:
http://shareapointkiran.blogspot.com/2010/02/error-while-installing-wss-moss.html#!/2010/02/error-while-installing-wss-moss.html

Also, look to see if you have any corrupt content databases and restore them from backup.

Comment: I tried the above said, and in fact the web.config file exists in 12/TEMPLATE/LAYOUTS already, so I backed up the file and overwrote it. When running the Sharepoint Product and Technologies Configuration Wizard after the change the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that running the product and technologies wizard after applying the WSS SP3 update will produce an error, however after running the MOSS SP3 update there won't be an error so I'd advise you apply SP3 for MOSS after applying WSS SP3. Have had this happen twice for me and then after which I subsequently migrated the farm to SharePoint 2010 without issue.

Comment: It seems that we didn't have MOSS 2007 after all, just WSS 3.0. So I'm not able to try yoursolution now.